# How to convert keycodes to key?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, c++, xev, keycodes

It's easy to get the keycode of a given key (showkey,xev etc) but how can one convert this keycode back to a key, for different keyboard layouts?
(key->keycode, and back)
For example:
keycode(MetaKey)=125 <=> key(125)=MetaKey

Comment: Related question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/596601/111181